# MySQL GROUBY counts is Inconsistent

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to find out product counts with **GROUP_BY** on **name**

However These 2 queries confused me a bit.

How can the count of distinct products (Which is 204 -> Query-A) be higher than actual number of products (Which is single -> Query-B)?

### **Query-A**

```
SELECT an.name
     , COUNT(DISTINCT product.productid) 
  FROM product 
  JOIN productkeywords pk 
    ON product.productid = pk.productid
  JOIN categorydisplayattributes cda 
    ON product.categoryid = cda.categoryid
  JOIN attributenames an 
    ON cda.attributeid = an.attributeid 
   AND an.name = 'Number of Fixed Shelves'
 WHERE pk.keywords LIKE '%mouse%' 
 GROUP 
    BY an.name
 LIMIT 100
```

### **Output-A**

```
name                     , COUNT(DISTINCT product.productid)
-------------------------+-------
'Number of Fixed Shelves', '204'
```

### **Query-B**

```
SELECT an.name, product.productid FROM product 
JOIN productkeywords pk ON product.productid = pk.productid
JOIN categorydisplayattributes cda ON product.categoryid = cda.categoryid
JOIN attributenames an ON cda.attributeid = an.attributeid AND an.name = 'Number of Fixed Shelves'
WHERE pk.keywords LIKE '%mouse%' 
GROUP BY an.name
LIMIT 100
```

### Output-B

```
name                     , productid
-------------------------+--------------
'Number of Fixed Shelves', '1025794284'
```

Comment: Query b has an invalid use of group by(no aggregate functions)  product.productid will be non determinate

Comment: I'm just lost.  What is "'Number of Fixed Shelves'".  It is not mentioned in any of the queries or the text.

Comment: GROUP BY in a subqeury before JOINing.

Comment: @gordonlinoff - looks like the value of `an.name` to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the `productid` to the `GROUP BY` you ensure one output row per `name`/`product` combination.

By leaving it out you were only get one row per `name`.  (And so it was being forced to pick one arbitrary `productid` from the list of 204 possible values.)

```
SELECT an.name, product.productid
FROM product 
JOIN productkeywords pk ON product.productid = pk.productid
JOIN categorydisplayattributes cda ON product.categoryid = cda.categoryid
JOIN attributenames an ON cda.attributeid = an.attributeid
 AND an.name = 'Number of Fixed Shelves'
WHERE pk.keywords LIKE '%mouse%' 
GROUP BY an.name, product.productid
```

(You also want to remove the LIMIT if you want all 204 rows.)